# Correctly order float counter (perpage.sty) while sharing eqn/thm counter

Tags: floats, theorems, counters

1. Sharing float (fig) and thm counter can be done with `\newtheorem{theorem}[figure]{Theorem}`.
2. Correctly ordering float (fig) counter based on  actual location in the PDF (as opposed to location in source code) can be done with `\MakeSorted{figure}` from `perpage.sty`.
3. Sharing float (fig) and eqn counter can be done with `\makeatletter\let\c@equation\c@figure\makeatother`.

I can do 1 and 2 together (see mwe-b).
I can do 1 and 3 together (see mwe-c).
*But I can't do all three together (see mwe-d).*

**Partial/fake solution.** I can skirt the issue by making a `myeqn` environment (see mwe-a).

**Question.** Is there an actual solution that allows you to keep the `equation` environment? Maybe one can resolve the clash in mwe-d by swapping `\c@figure` out for something (based on the precise implementation of `perpage.sty`)? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: mwe-a]
[image: mwe-b]
[image: mwe-c]
[image: mwe-d]

```
%% MWE-A
\documentlass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newtheorem{theorem}[figure]{Theorem} %1
\usepackage{perpage}\MakeSorted{figure} %2
\newenvironment{myeqn}
  {\stepcounter{figure}\hfill\begin{math}}
  {\end{math}\hfill(\arabic{figure})}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\blindtext\end{theorem}
\begin{figure}\blindtext\caption{Caption}\end{figure}
\begin{myeqn}a^2+b^2=c^2\end{myeqn}
\end{document}

%% MWE-B
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newtheorem{theorem}[figure]{Theorem} %1
\usepackage{perpage}\MakeSorted{figure} %2
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\blindtext\end{theorem}
\begin{figure}\blindtext\caption{Caption}\end{figure}
\begin{equation}a^2+b^2=c^2\end{equation}
\end{document}

%% MWE-C
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newtheorem{theorem}[figure]{Theorem} %1
\makeatletter\let\c@equation\c@figure\makeatother %3
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\blindtext\end{theorem}
\begin{figure}\blindtext\caption{Caption}\end{figure}
\begin{equation}a^2+b^2=c^2\end{equation}
\end{document}

%% MWE-D
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newtheorem{theorem}[figure]{Theorem} %1
\usepackage{perpage}\MakeSorted{figure} %2
\makeatletter\let\c@equation\c@figure\makeatother %3
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\blindtext\end{theorem}
\begin{figure}\blindtext\caption{Caption}\end{figure}
\begin{equation}a^2+b^2=c^2\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making a new `myeqn` environment, just modify the `equation` environment. The solution seems to play fine with `perpage`'s `\MakeSorted` (the numbering looks as expected).

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{%
    \setcounter{equation}{\value{figure}}%
    \stepcounter{figure}%
    }
\renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{figure}}
```

The last line above replaces the `equation` counter's printout with the `figure` counter's printout, because the `equation` counter can be incorrect when `\MakeSorted` renumbers the floats based on display order. Thus, the line `\setcounter{equation}{\arabic{figure}}` above is unnecessary and can be deleted (the line is just to insure against accidental referral to the `equation` counter).

Similarly, because `perpage` clashes with `chngcntr`'s `\counterwithin`, you can modify `\section` if you want to reset your counter each section.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\section{\setcounter{figure}0}
```

The patch seems to work as long as you don't have too many sections and floats close to each other, ie, on the same page.

**Edit.** Here are two mwe's: just the equation fix (mwe-e), and the equation fix with the count within section fix (mwe-f).

```
%% MWE-E
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum, amsthm, perpage, etoolbox}
\newtheorem{theorem}[figure]{Theorem} % sync thm, float
\MakeSorted{figure} % renumber float
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\stepcounter{figure}} % sync eqn, float
\renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{figure}} % sync eqn, float

\begin{document}
\section*{This is a section}
\begin{theorem}This is a theorem.\end{theorem}
\begin{figure}\lipsum[2]\caption{This is a caption}\end{figure}
\begin{equation}a^2+b^2=c^2\end{equation}
\section*{Another section}
\begin{theorem}[This is a Title]\lipsum[2]\end{theorem}
\begin{equation}a^2+b^2=c^2\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe-e]

```
%% MWE-F
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum, amsthm, perpage, etoolbox}
\newtheorem{theorem}[figure]{Theorem}
\MakeSorted{figure}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\stepcounter{figure}}
\renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}} % count within sec
\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}} % count within sec
\preto\section{\setcounter{figure}0} % count within sec

\begin{document}
\section{This is a section}
\begin{theorem}This is a theorem.\end{theorem}
\begin{figure}\lipsum[2]\caption{This is a caption}\end{figure}
\begin{equation}a^2+b^2=c^2\end{equation}
\section{Another section}
\begin{theorem}[This is a Title]\lipsum[2]\end{theorem}
\begin{equation}a^2+b^2=c^2\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe-f]